# ansible json_query with character "-"

Tags: ansible

I have this json file and I need extract some data but problem is with this character -

```
{
    "changed": true,
    "failed": false,
    "meta": {
        "request_url": "pm/config/adom/AMIS/obj/dynamic/interface",
        "response_code": 0,
        "response_data": [
            {
                "color": 0,
                "defmap-zonemember": [],
                "description": "BYOD VLAN sub-interface.\nUsed in policy for firewalls maintaining BYOD traffic on LIBOs",
                "dynamic_mapping": null,
                "name": "BYOD",
                "single-intf": "enable"
            },
            {
                "color": 0,
                "defmap-zonemember": [],
                "dynamic_mapping": [
                    {
                        "_scope": [
                            {
                                "name": "ftg02",
                                "vdom": "dev"
                            }
                        ],
                        "intrazone-deny": "enable",
                        "local-intf": [
                            "port8"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "DMZ",
                "single-intf": "disable"
            },
            {
                "color": 0,
                "defmap-zonemember": [],
                "description": "Guest VLAN sub-interface. Used in policy for firewalls maintaining Guestnet traffic on LIBOs",
                "dynamic_mapping": null,
                "name": "Guest",
                "single-intf": "enable"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get result  of this "name": "DMZ"  - DMZ with some condition
if local-intf == port8
I have got this error
FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'local'. String: {{ item | json_query('dynamic_mapping[0]['local-intf'][0]') }}"}

here is my playbook which does not work \

```
- name: interface
  debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ interface_info.meta.response_data }}"
  when: 
    - item.dynamic_mapping != 'null'
    - item | json_query('dynamic_mapping[0]._scope[0].name') == 'ftg02'
    - item | json_query('dynamic_mapping[0]._scope[0].vdom') == 'dev'
    - item | json_query('dynamic_mapping[0]['local-intf'][0]) == 'port8'  #this line does not work
```

is some way to dont use loop ? Loop is to slow .

thank you for help

Comment: You should clarify the case a bit. The attributes *_scope* and *local-intf* are lists. The purpose of lists is to keep more items, not only one. Otherwise, why use a list when a single item shall be stored? Do you want to use the first items from these lists only? Or, shall the conditions rather look for membership in a list? The same is valid for *dynamic_mapping*.

Comment: `dynamic_mapping[0]."local-intf"[0]` simple and double quotes do not have the same meaning in JMESPath. So, `- item | json_query('dynamic_mapping[0]["local-intf"][0]') == 'port8'`

Comment: Hello @VladimirBotka , this is output from Fortinet firewall manager, I don't know why developers create everywhere list even there will be just one value. For me does not make any sense. I need to check zone , zone is key and value name": "DMZ", but I need to put condition if input firewall name is same as "name": "ftg02" in _scope. With loop I am able now to do it but loop is too slow if you have more then 1000 firewall so I need to use json_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ interface_info.meta.response_data|
                 selectattr('dynamic_mapping')|
                 selectattr('dynamic_mapping.0.local-intf.0', '==', 'port8')|
                 selectattr('dynamic_mapping.0._scope.0.name', '==', 'ftg02')|
                 selectattr('dynamic_mapping.0._scope.0.vdom', '==', 'dev')|
                 map(attribute='name')|first }}"
```

should give the first item

```yaml
  msg: DMZ
```